# Seams on tiled wall after lightbaking in unity

Tags: unity, tiles, lightmap, seams

I spent several days now trying to fix the seams in my unity scene whenever I hit the lightbaking button.

My setup is a wall out of different parts created in blender and then stitched together in unity.

I already tried to change every single setting in the Lighting>Scene window. Nothing seams to fix the problem -> after baking there are light seams between the wall parts and when I zoom out the seams are dark/black. See screenshots, they probably explain best.
[image: this is the setup of the wall parts][image: light seams][image: dark seams][image: lighting settings]

Comment: Have you already seen [Lightmapping-SeamStitching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Lightmapping-SeamStitching.html) and set `Stitch Seams` as true in `MeshRenderer`?

Comment: Yes, lightmapping seam stitching is activated on all wall parts. That is unfortunately not the solution

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with the lightmap UVs? See [https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProgressiveLightmapper-UVOverlap.html](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProgressiveLightmapper-UVOverlap.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the baked global illumination debug view to see what the texel density. You can also check UV charts to see if there is a hard break at the seams. Your lighting settings look good, I suspect it's an issue with the models themselves.